# How do i fix this function in python? Im the definition of a noob at python, still learning, so please help. Its suppposed to ask for the name and age

Tags: python

```
def say_hi(x, y):                                                                              

name = x         
age = y  
print("Hello " + name + ". You are " + age + " years old. Is this correct?" )


x = input("Enter your name: ")
y = input("Enter your age: ")



say_hi()
```

#i know the answer to this question is probably simple as hell but please help, i really want to get good at coding and make my own programs.

Comment: you need to pass `x` and `y` to `say_hi` like `say_hi(x,y)`

Comment: Please fix the indentation to show which lines are in the function and which are in the caller.

Comment: There's no need to assign the parameters to different variables. Just define the function `def say_hi(name, age):`

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things your code is missing.

- In Python, program flow is controlled by using indentation. The contents of the function should be indented (using tabs or spaces at the start of each line), so that it's clear that those lines of code belong to the function `say_hi()`.
- When calling a function, the variables that it uses should be passed to it inside the parentheses, like this: `say_hi("A name", "an age")`.
- You may also want to use meaningful variable names in your function definitions, so that it's clear what each parameter is supposed to be used for

Here's some improved code with comments explaining what I've done

```py
# Function definition contains clear variable names
# Code inside the function is indented correctly
def say_hi(name, age):
    print("Hello " + name + ". You are " + age + " years old. Is this correct?" )

# Outside the function definition, we get the user's input
x = input("Enter your name: ")
y = input("Enter your age: ")

# And when we call the function, we give it the 
# variables so that Python knows what we want to use as arguments
say_hi(x, y)
```

I hope this helps! I'd highly recommend looking at some beginner's programming courses on YouTube, since seeing some real-world examples will hopefully help you along a lot with writing good code. If you're not already, you may want to try out a code editor (I use VS Code, but there's tons of options), which will help you find simple errors like these more easily by putting red underlines where it thinks there's an error (much like a document editor does for spelling). Best of luck with programming in the future!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass x and y into the function like this -

```
say_hi(x,y)
```